# Can I use WPA_Supplicant to hardcode a specific MAC address?

Tags: networking, wifi, dhcp, wpa-supplicant, mac-address

I'm trying to use a raspberry pi as an HTTP server from my home network. I have to do this via a USB wireless adapter instead of CAT5 for a number of reasons that I won't get into.

Problem is, I can't port-forward this device from my router consistently, because the DHCP reservation I have set up for it doesn't hold. I found out that my MAC address is different every time my pi reconnects.

Is there some way I can hardcode a specific MAC address into wpa_supplicant, or into some other script I can set to run at boot?

**Edit:**

My solution was to replace the systemd init script for wpa_supplicant with one that uses ifconfig to set the MAC prior to starting wpa_supplicant. Not exactly the cleanest solution, but it works well enough that I don't need a different fix.

Comment: Either you hardcode it in a configuration file (cannot remember the specifics I am afraid), or you use a wifi pen.

Comment: Alternative: configure a static IP address instead of using DHCP.

Comment: do not edit the question, had your own answer.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I don't think it technically counts as a solution because it wasn't quite what I was asking for.

Comment: it is not up for wpa_supplicant to do that anyway.

Comment: @EthanMcTague: Workarounds count as answers.  You called it “My solution”; solutions don’t belong in the question.